# LINQ: Find item from list with desired key value, and if not null, do something with it

Tags: .net, list, linq

I have list of categories and every category has key `Name` and key `Items` which is list of files.
I want to extract category with desired Name from list (if not found, return `null`). And then check, if category not `null`, fill its `Items`...

```
categories = List<Category>
var desiredCategory = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "DesiredName");

desiredCategory - if not null ?

foreach (var file in files)
{
    desiredCategory.Items.Add(file);
}
```

This above is representative code what I want to achieve, my question is: how can it be done in most simpler way? Using LINQ or whatever?

EDIT: And what if I don't want to operate on `desiredCategory` variable but continue directly on `categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "DesiredName")` ?

For example:

```
categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "DesiredName").WhenIsNotNull()...
```

How to do it inisde brackets of `WhenIsNotNull` ?

Comment: what you tried so far..?

Comment: What is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Given these are logically two separate actions (finding the category with the desired name, populating the category's items), i dont see the above approach as a problem. You might be able to tidy up the code a bit:

```
categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals("desiredname", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

If you're sure you only expect there to be one or none, use single and catch resulting exception. When comparing the value of strings, you should use Equals override and provide a comparison hint.

And then, for the items:

`desiredCategory.Items.AddRange(files)`

---

After the edit.

You could do this with an extension method:

```
public static void WhenNotNull<T>(this T item)
{
    if (item != default(T))
        // Do stuff
}
```